# Visual Studio Debugger - How to quickly find which part of a long if statment return false

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, javascript-debugger

I am looking for a quick way to identify the part inside a complicated if condition will cause the whole condition to return false.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the dis-assembly view. In Visual Studio: Debug -> Windows -> Disassembly.
Run step by step, and try to understand what the processor does.

Also, if you 'if' statement doesn't have function call, you can evaluate (in the expression evaluation window) each part of your 'if' statement